# Calendar as Lockscreen/Wallpaper

Tags: calendar, lock-screen

I'm looking for a magic way of having a daily or weekly calendar as a lockscreen wallpaper or desktop background on my kids' laptops. I know if they have to screen capture Outlook and update it themselves it won't happen.

They all have Windows laptops for school and they are forever forgetting homework tasks, before and after school activities and tuition sessions. Because they don't use their laptops for everything having notifications doesn't always work as well as needing Outlook open for them to work. They are not allowed phones in school. The calendar widget on the windblows 10 lockscreen only shows the next appointment, not everything, and is pretty useless. I want them to have a full screen view of their daily and weekly commitments so they can quickly glance the lockscreen in between classes etc and see what's coming up.

I don't mind if I need a 3rd party app to display outlook's content, capture an image, export to and capture from Google calendar, or even something that needs to run on a Linux machine and sync an image. As long as I can do it automatically for each kid's calendar and machine. If it helps them to never miss another tuition session I'll be happy.

Answer (score 0):

You could use
[Outlook on the Desktop](https://outlookonthedesktop.com/),
which is donation-ware:

[image]

Comment: Gave OotD a go. Unfortunately it doesn't do shared calendars, you can only show the default one. And as the name suggests, it only appears on the desktop.